# C# update code for logout using mysql

Tags: c#, mysql, database

im doing an update statement where the datetimepicker(logout) will insert into the same row as login but its making another row when i logout  here is the link : https://i.stack.imgur.com/dW8TG.jpg

ps. the problem here is the logout button is inserting into another row.. but i want to insert it in the same row.

here is my code :

```
  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         con.Open();
            MySqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandText = "select * from empinfo where username = '" + label4.Text + "' and IDNUMBER = '" + textBox1.Text + "' ";
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            da.Fill(dt);
            i = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows.Count.ToString());


            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Input your id number");


            }

            else if (i == 0)
            {

                MessageBox.Show("Username and IDNUMBER didn't match.", "Log-In Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);


            }
            else
            {
                updateuser();
              login frmm = new login();
                frmm.Show();
                this.Close();

            }
            con.Close();



        }
              public void updateuser()
    {
        MySqlConnection cnn = new MySqlConnection(mysqlAddress);
        MySqlCommand cmdupdate;
        cnn.Open();
        try
        {
            cmdupdate = cnn.CreateCommand();
            cmdupdate.CommandText = "update employee set logout = @logout";
            cmdupdate.CommandText = "Insert into employee (logout) values (@logout)";
            cmdupdate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@logout", dateTimePicker1.Value);

            cmdupdate.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (cnn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                cnn.Close();

                MessageBox.Show("Data has been saved");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You have 2 commands doing the same thing in different ways - `update employee` and `insert into employee`. The `update` command will update the record with the appropriate information; and `insert` creates a new record. These are two separate commands.

Comment: i see... i used insert and  2 parameters at the same time . but how can i set the proper syntax for update? to put the logout in the same row..

Comment: are you using windows forms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should create different methods for login and logout like

For LOGIN

```
    public static long id;
public void loginuser()
                {
                    MySqlConnection cnn = new MySqlConnection(mysqlAddress);
                    MySqlCommand cmd;
                    cnn.Open();
                    try
                    {
                        cmd = cnn.CreateCommand();
                        cmd.CommandText = "Insert into employee (logout) values (@logout)";
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@login", DateTime.Now);

                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        id = cmd.LastInsertedId; // it will return the id of last inserted row

                    }
                    catch (Exception)
                    {
                        throw;
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        if (cnn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                        {
                            cnn.Close();

                            MessageBox.Show("Data has been saved");
                        }
                    }
                }
```

For LOGOUT

```
public void logoutuser()
            {
                MySqlConnection cnn = new MySqlConnection(mysqlAddress);
                MySqlCommand cmd;
                cnn.Open();
                try
                {
                    cmd = cnn.CreateCommand();
                    cmd.CommandText = "update employee set logout = @logout WHERE IDNUMBER=@ID";
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@logout", dateTimePicker1.Value);
                  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", id);
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();


                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    throw;
                }
                finally
                {
                    if (cnn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                    {
                        cnn.Close();

                        MessageBox.Show("Data has been saved");
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: this is for login form right, 
Why is it for logout?
 cmd.CommandText = "Insert into employee (logout) values (@logout)";

Comment: Change int id to long id

Comment: and you can change the variable @logout to any name you want

Comment: i tried your code for logout but it didn't saved into my table..
http://imgur.com/a/NcKij

Comment: form 2 .id is static field? also place a beakpoint to check the id

Comment: this is what happened.. 
i put the public void loginuser() to form2 
Then the public void logout user is into another form
http://imgur.com/a/9yToq

Comment: `class Test
{
    public static long id{ get; set; }
}` and set Test.id =  cmd.LastInsertedId and in logout get Test.id

Answer (score 1):

As @Ben in the comments pointed out, you do not need to use insert and only want update so change your code like this:

```
try
        {
            cmdupdate = cnn.CreateCommand();
            cmdupdate.CommandText = "update employee set logout=@logout";
            cmdupdate.CommandText += "WHERE IDNUMBER=@IDNUMBER";
            cmdupdate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IDNUMBER", textBox1.Text.Trim());
            cmdupdate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@logout", dateTimePicker1.Value);

            cmdupdate.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
```

The Where is to make sure it only updates the IDNUMBER on the textbox.

Comment: Fatal error encountered during command execution.

i got fatal from catch 
Fatal error encountered during command execution.

Comment: unless your 'dateTimePicker1.Value' is the same one being used on both login and logout then whatever the value is, it will be the value inserted in your table regardless of how many many times a user logins.

Comment: the throw from catch encountered fatal error so i removed it then there's no error but it didn't save the value for logout in the database

Comment: Would it be possible to post a picture of your tables? Cause as of the moment I do not see what would cause an error in command execution.